# Any studies on lack of imagination and creativity?

Tags: cognitive-psychology

Is there a formal scientific term for this type of personality?:

1. Main priorities are: family, phsyical and financial protection of the family and self. (Little to no creativity. Strong desire to reproduce.)
2. Learning a process or a system with no desire to improve process/system in any substantial way.
3. Avoidance of major change. Strong attraction for familiarity and incremental improvement only.
4. Understanding through physical experiences but with medium to low abstract thinking skills. (Low imagination.)
5. Attraction to physical movement (as participant or spectator): dance,  slapstick comedy, sports. Avoidance of certain mental activities. (Jock stereotype.)

Apologies for my lack of scientific bg. I have no formal edu.

The reason I ask is because I am building a UI and this "personality" appears to be dominant among the mass market. However, I have no idea where to begin when it comes to science journals and psychology terms.

Comment: Yes there are studies on lack of imagination and creativity.

Comment: @guesoij Could you give references or indication of relevant terms?

Comment: @dgo.a: Yes, strictly formally scientifically speaking, it is know as the "male". For example using your points, 1) Sex, belonging and protection. 2) Why improve it unless it directly helps me achieve #1? 3) Path of least difficulty and laziness. 4) Unless it directly happens to me why should I think about it. 5) I don't want to think and show me things that look good.

Comment: That is a common human you described. Our primary goal is survival until reproduction. Creativity is something that helps us in that process, but it is not mandatory. Foregoing basic needs in favor of higher values comes with smaller chance of success but bigger prize. I will have to see if I can come up with a scientific basis behind this before I start name calling, but even if there is a basis: will it be smart to label these two types? Instead of motivating people, you will most likely enrage a bunch.

Answer (score 3):

Personality and individual differences research has a range of constructs that relate to what you are talking about:

- [conservatism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservatism#Psychology) or fear of uncertainty seems relevant
- Low levels of [openness to experience](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Openness_to_experience)

You seem to describing a "type" of individual. However, a multidimensional continuous approach is probably a better model of individual differences. For example, you describe a person with low intelligence (i.e., concrete thinking, low abstract reasoning). However, from memory intelligence and traits like openness only correlate weakly if at all.
Thus, the characteristics you describe don't necessarily go together. 
What you seem to be describing is a stereotype, which probably has a poor match to reality where people tend to vary on a range of factors. Sure you can probably point to some point who fit the type, but there will be plenty more than only reflect some of those characteristics.

With regards to a person's main desires being protection of self and family both physically and financially, this sounds like a description of a lot of people. There are plenty of motivational theories and evolutionary models of human psychology which would reinforce such motives as very important to people.